# Branch by Abstraction in Java

Tags: java

We have gone through article Branch by Abstraction and We are trying to implement this concept.

We are using Spring IOC to inject class dynamically.

Let say we have two Supplier ; Old Supplier and New Supplier. Using Spring IOC we will inject New Supplier for some client code and Old Supplier for some client code.

Now we have a Model class(Common class) which is being used by both the supplier.
We want to add some new field (property) in Model class and that field should be available to only New Supplier but not to Old Supplier. We can not inject Model class because we have to create N number of object of Model class in our logic.

How can we achieve Abstraction for Model class? Please guide us if anybody have knowledge

Comment: If you have to re-instantiate your Model class multiple times, then why do not you create an Abstract Model class and two child Model classes. NewModel and OldModel with required properties.

Comment: @Prashant : then How to toggle between these 2 model classes.we have already implemented toggle for Supplier

Comment: The same way you did for Supplier.. I assume the business logic of differentiation will remain the same..

Comment: I am not sure if this is the right/expected way.. this is a solution that I came across when I read your problem.

Comment: @Prashant No this is not expected way.